# Drop cap creates unwanted empty space inside table cell

Tags: tables, lettrine, drop-cap

I am using the Lettrine package for creating a drop cap letter within a table cell. However, this generates an unwanted empty line before the text (or, perhaps, the text is vertically aligned to the bottom of the cell). See the following minimal code (compiled on XeTeX):

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{p{.45\linewidth}p{.45\linewidth}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Left column} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Right column} \\ \hline
\lettrine{S}{}pecial text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter.  &
Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image]
Any idea on how to adjust that? I need both cells aligned vertically to the top, with no empty lines ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unwanted vertical skip doesn't show up with E, T, M, f.i., only for "round" letters like S, O, G, C which are usually slightly taller than other capitals.

**Recommended fix**: The default value of `\DiscardVskip` is too short for your example. You can enlarge it for the whole document with

`\usepackage[novskip=1pt]{lettrine}` % requires lettrine v.2.30

or

`\setlength{\DiscardVskip}{1pt}`      % all versions

Another possible fix would be to add option `refstring` to the `\lettrine` command: `\lettrine[refstring]{S}{pecial}`.  But with this fix you get a sub-optimal drop cap (slightly too short).

Btw. using a second void argument `\lettrine{S}{}` is not recommended. If you don't want small caps, add `\renewcommand*{\LettrineTextFont}{}` after loading the `lettrine` package.

Finally, "smashing" the drop cap, coding `\lettrine{\smash{S}}{}`, means lying to the command `\lettrine` about the drop cap's height and depth, this could have very nasty side effects… I wouldn't do that (a `\smash` command is already included in the `\lettrine` code anyway).

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked fine to me. Also, thank you for your useful Lettrine package ))

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't say whether this "fix" will always give what you want, but in this case, one can `\smash` the `S` before applying the `\lettrine`.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lettrine}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{p{.45\linewidth}p{.45\linewidth}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Left column} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Right column} \\ \hline
\lettrine{\smash{S}}{}pecial text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter. Special text starting with a drop cap letter.  &
Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. Normal text without the drop cap. \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this might work as a work around.

Comment: But for some reasons it does not work in my real file...